# wifi bridge and traceroute

Tags: linux, wifi

I have 2 wireless bridges connected to DSL. I'd like see the path of my connection from my pc to internet.

traceroute works at layer 3, bridges works at layer 2. Is there a command like traceroute that works at layer2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask is simply not possible: as a layer 2 protocol, ARP/MAC resolution is not routable. This means that a MAC traceroute can not exist, as it need a layer 3 protocol to carry path information.